# Ruby : Help about a regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this huge string :

```
Name : totoAge : 18Country : Unknown
```

And I want to take only "toto", "18" and "Unknown".
I tried something like Name : (.+$) to have only "toto" but doesn't work.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Don't you have any separator between `toto` and `Age` or between `18` and `Country`?

Comment: Not, that's why it's hard for me :/

Comment: To extract name, let's say, you can use a = "Name : totoAge : 18Country : Unknown" and then `a[/Name : (\w*)/,1][0..-4]
`.. Does that work for you? Should I add an answer with such formats for all three?

Comment: Where does the string come from? The missing separator looks like a conversion error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a pattern. I think you are looking for this,

```
(?<=:\s)\w+(?=$)|(?<=:\s)[a-z0-9]+
```

[DEMO](http://www.rubular.com/r/zcZMXGjh41)

OR

Try the below regex if you want to mention `Name`, `Age`, `Country` in your pattern,

```
(?<=Name : |Age : |Country : )[A-Z]?[a-z0-9]+
```

[DEMO](http://www.rubular.com/r/CwgeiLW5RP)

Comment: OR you could try this if you want to mention name or country http://www.rubular.com/r/CwgeiLW5RP.

Comment: It is partly the OP's fault for not being clear, but I think that a reasonable interpretation of the question is that it is coincidence that the capitalized term `Unknown` is placed the last in the string, and your regex relies on that.

Comment: First it seems a little bit unclear. Then i added a second option to my answer.

Comment: you could try this also [`(?<=: )[A-Z]?[a-z0-9]+`](http://www.rubular.com/r/osZ57CCusj)

Answer (score 0):

This might help you out.

```
s = 'Name : totoAge : 18Country : Unknown'
temp = s.split /(?=[A-Z])/
result = temp.each {|d| r << d.split(':').last.strip}
final_output = result.reject(&:empty?)
```

And you have the result. Tell me if you need more help on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do would be as follows:

Let's say, you can use `s = "Name : totoAge : 18Country : Unknown"`

Name:  `s[/Name : (\w*)/,1][0..-4]`

Age :  `s[/Age : (\w*)/,1][0..-8]`

Country: `s[/Country : (\w*)/,1]`

This is better than other methods, because they are using an uppercase, digit etc. to split the string whereas the Name, Country etc. may contain uppercase, digit etc.

Hope it helps :)